# проверка массива на наличие значений

Tags: delphi

Как запоминать все использованные значения в массиве и для каждого нового значения проверять, есть ли оно в массиве или нет? Желательно ответ сопровождать кодом.

Comment: Например пробегать по всему массиву и искать в нем нужные значения. А код вы уж как-нибудь сами...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 3):

Для таких действий в Delphi [существует](http://www.delphi.int.ru/articles/123/) тип "множество".
Описание и присвоение множества:

```
var
  // Можно использовать только простые типы до 256 значений (Byte, AnsiChar, и т.п.) 
  A: set of Byte;

A := [1,3,4];
```

Добавление элемента:

```
A := A + [5];
```

Проверка:

```
if x in A then ShowMessage('Элемент находится во множестве A.');
```

Comment: В современных версиях Делфи, тип `Char` это `WideChar` и если его использовать в сете, то он будет обрезан до 1 байта. Поэтому лучше так не делать, а использовать сразу байт.

Comment: @Krom Stern Я хотел дать понятие "множество". ТС вообще не упоминал, с какими типами данных он работает.

Answer (score 3):

Правильнее всего будет воспользоваться дженериковскими классами, это даст хороший "задел на будущее". В частности, для вашей задачи больше всего подойдет TDictionary - класс, работающий с парами ключ-значение. Он позволяет очень быстро работать с элементами "внутреннего массива" по "ключевому типу". Значения в поле "Ключ" уникальны и не повторяемы, что нам и необходимо.

Для примера, представим что стоит задача работы с "массивом" строк. В качестве ключа выбираем строку (поскольку нужно обеспечить ее уникальность), а значение можно выбрать любым, возьмем простейшее - integer (все равно пока мы его не используем):

```pascal
type
  TMyDictionary = TDictionary<string, integer>;

var
  myDict: TMyDictionary;
  tmpKey: string;
begin
  myDict:=TMyDictionary.Create;
  try
    // добавляем новый ключ, если его еще нет в словаре.
    // если есть - то Value у этого ключа останется прежним
    if not myDict.ContainsKey['123'] then
      myDict.Add('123', 123);

    // если нам все равно, что будет в полях Value
    // или если нужно в любом случае перезаписать на новое значение:
    myDict.AddOrSetValue('123', 123);

    // остальные действия Dictionary выполнит сам -
    // быстро найдет, существует ли новый ключ
    // и так же быстро запишет новые данные (при необходимости)
    // в отличие от массивов и списков Dictionary не использует полный перебор внутренних данных

    // проход по всем ключам словаря (выводим все элементы "массива"):
    for tmpKey in myDict.Keys do
      ShowMessage(tmpKey);
  finally
    myDict.Free;
  end;
end;
```

TDictionary также хорошо работает со сложными парами ключ-значение, например - с `record`-ами и объектами, однако в этом случае его нужно создавать с собственной реализацией IEqualityComparer, что является темой отдельного обсуждения.

Comment: Плюсик за описание современных возможностей.

Comment: Описание типа можно выкинуть. Зачем оно? А вместо `TMyDictionary` подставлять везде `TDictionary<string, integer>`. Так будет сразу видно какой словарь используется. А что такое `TMyDictionary` не сразу разберешься. Это удобно, особенно когда читаешь чужой большой сложный код.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci В данном конкретном случае действительно объявление излишне. Однако (дальше - имхо) с развитием проекта часто становится необходимо дополнить класс методами и/или свойствами (к примеру - запись/чтение из потока). В этом случае указание в коде `TDict<>` будет мешать - вместо "просто добавить новый код" получится "добавить новый и изменить кучу старого". Поэтому прямое объявление, на мой взгляд, допустимо и оправданно для локального использования, в пределах одного метода, максимум - нескольких.

Comment: @kami согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем простенько тогда так:

```
type
    TMyArray = array of integer;

//функция проверки на уникальность
function IsUnique(Arr: TMyArray; Const Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for I := 0 to Length(Arr) - 1 do
  begin
    If Arr[I] = Value Then
      Exit(False);
  end;
end;

//основной код программы
var
  UniqueArray: TMyArray;
  NewValue: integer;
  ArrLen: integer;
begin
  SetLength(UniqueArray, 0);

  //тут может быть добавление элементов в цикле
  NewValue := 10; 
  If IsUnique(UniqueArray, NewValue) Then
  begin
    ArrLen := length(UniqueArray);
    SetLength(UniqueArray, ArrLen + 1);
    UniqueArray[ArrLen - 1] := NewValue;
  end;
end;
```

Если не использовать массив - можно воспользоватся `StringList'ом` у него есть опция `Duplicates`, которая позволит игнорировать дубликаты. Все нюансы описаны в статье "[Список уникальных значений](http://mirsovetov.net/delphi-unique-list.html)"